# Realizando migraciones en Django - django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null values

Tags: python, django, django-models

Estoy adicionando el siguiente atributo tipo `choice` a mi modelo

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    GENDER_MALE = 'M'
    GENDER_FEMALE = 'F'
    GENDER_OTHER = 'O'
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (GENDER_MALE, u'male'),
        (GENDER_FEMALE, u'female'),
        (GENDER_OTHER, u'other'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=GENDER_OTHER,)
```

Cuando yo ejecuto la migración, me dice lo siguiente:

```
(nrb_dev)➜  project git:(master) ✗ python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'userprofile':
  0010_auto_20160116_2219.py:
    - Alter field gender on user
(nrb_dev)➜  project git:(master) ✗ python manage.py migrate 


Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: sessions, userprofile, auth, admin, contenttypes
Running migrations:
  Applying userprofile.0006_auto_20160116_2206...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: column "gender" contains null values


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 396, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "gender" contains null values

(nrb_dev)➜  project git:(master) ✗
```

Me dice que el atributo o columna `gender` que estoy adicionando ya contiene un valor nulo, pero no entiendo si a un campo tipo choice a partir de una tupla se le deba especificar algo más al definirlo.

[Estoy siguiendo el ejemplo como Django lo recomienda](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) pero no se cual es mi error.

El código de la migración que se intenta aplicar es este:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9 on 2016-01-16 22:19
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('userprofile', '0009_auto_20160116_2214'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='gender',
            field=models.CharField(choices=[('M', 'male'), ('F', 'female'), ('O', 'other')], default='O', max_length=1),
        ),
    ]
```

Por otro lado, que es mas recomendable, ¿que en un formulario el usuario escoja el género (masculino y femenino) utilizando un select box o es mejor un item tipo radio button?

Comment: Hola, puedes agregar el código de `0010_auto_20160116_2219.py`. Me gustaría verlo antes de soltar algunas ideas

Comment: Hola César, lo he adicionado editando mi pregunta.

Comment: ¿Anteriormente el campo ya existía y ahora le estas agregado el choices? Si es asi, ¿en la definición anterior tenía `null=True`?

Comment: Lo que sucede es que hice esa migración varias veces, pero siempre con el parametro choices, y nunca le he puesto 'null=True'. ¿Será que borro las migraciones y las vuelvo a ejecutar?

Comment: Cuando dices que lo has hecho varias veces es porque la aplicabas y la desaplicabas o en migraciones distintas? Si, de hecho lo mas facil es borrarlo y hacerlo de nuevo pero ten en cuenta que tienes que borrar los registros de la tabla `django_migrations`

Comment: Borre los registros de la tabla `django_migrations` y ejecuté de nuevo la migración y obtive este mensaje `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" already exists` Es que creo que debi mejor desaplicar la migración en lugar de borrar registros físicamente, ahora también me dice que hay campos relacionados con `auth_permission` ... Creo que miraré a ver si puedo deshacer la migración aunque no creo jaja

Comment: Si, tenías que haber desaplicado primero. Supongo que puedes buscar el registro en `django_content_type` que corresponda al `app_label` y `model` de tu tabla, con ese ID borra los registros en `auth_permission` correspondientes a `content_type_id`, luego borras el registro de la tabla `django_content_type`. Imagino que debería funcionar.

Comment: Si, me puse a borrar de forma transitiva los registros con los id  correspondientes,  pero llegué a un punto en el que a pesar de que llevé la cuenta de lo que eliminaba, no efectué la migración y en cambio me confundi con tantas cambios manuales que hice. (Un error newbe tal vez)

Comment: Lo que hice fue volver a clonar mi proyecto desde mi repositorio y lei un poco de la documentación en Django, en donde dice aquí https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake-initial que la opción `--fake-initial puede usarse para efectuar una migración con una base de datos a la cual ya le haya hecho migraciones. USe esa opción y me fue de esta manera

Comment: `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: contenttypes, sessions, auth, userprofile, admin
Running migrations:
  Applying userprofile.0006_user_gender... OK
(nrb_dev)➜  neurorehabilitation-system git:(master) ✗`

Comment: Perfecto, puedes responder tu propia pregunta y aceptarla

Comment: Después ejecute `python manage.py migrate` y me funcionó, pero me queda de lección aplicar y desaplicar las migraciones, es lo correcto. Podŕia haber podido cuadrar el error manualmente, pero creo que algo hice malo en borrar algunos registros. GRacias :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay algo muy útil a tener en cuenta al momento de establecer una migración y es que si sobre la base de datos ya se han establecido migraciones con anterioridad, debe hacerse una migración falsa [tal como se explica en la documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake-initial)

```
(nrb_dev)➜  neurorehabilitation-system git:(dev) ✗ python manage.py makemigrations

Migrations for 'userprofile':
  userprofile.0006_user_gender.py:
    - Add field gender on user
(nrb_dev)➜ neurorehabilitation-system git:(master) ✗ python manage.py migrate --fake-initial 
Operations to perform: Apply all migrations: contenttypes, sessions, auth, userprofile, admin Running migrations: Applying userprofile.0006_user_gender... OK 
(nrb_dev)➜ neurorehabilitation-system git:(master) ✗
```

De esta manera ya en mi base de datos se ha aplicado la migración adicionando el nuevo campo `gender` que era el que quería.

Adicional a ello, [encontré este post que es muy útil](http://www.marinamele.com/how-to-correctly-remove-a-model-or-app-in-django) en donde se habla acerca de como remover una aplicación o modelo en Django, de la manera correcta para que la base de datos no se vaya a ver afectada.